# How do I get my HighScore to display instantly in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: xcode, swift

I figured out how to save my highscore but I am having one problem. The highscore saves but it doesn't update the highscore after I beat the score. I have to play again and lose then it updates the highscore in the game over menu. How would I fix this? Here is the code.

```
  func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){

    var defaults=NSUserDefaults()
    var highscore=defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    if(score>highscore)
    {
        defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
    }
    var highscoreshow = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    endOfGameHighScoreLabel.text = String(highscore)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `highscoreshow` variable you've declared instead of using the `highscore` variable. Because in your `highscore` variable there is still the highscore from one round before. And as you've already done, you need to get the new highscore which you saved in your `NSUserDefaults`. So you need to change that:

```
endOfGameHighScoreLabel.text = String(highscore)
```

To that:

```
endOfGameHighScoreLabel.text = String(highscoreshow)
```